# htmlParse errors on accessing google search. Is their an alternative approach

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to obtain the number of results obtained from specific google searches. 
For example for stackoverflow there are "About 28,200,000 results (0.12 seconds)".

Normally I would use the xpathSApply function from the XML R package but I am having errors and am not sure how to solve them or know if there is an alternative approach

```
library(XML)
googleURL <- "https://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow"
googleInfo <- htmlParse(googleURL, isURL = TRUE)
Error: failed to load external entity "https://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow"

#use of RCurl which I am not that familiar with
library(RCurl)
getURL(googleURL)
#Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
 #error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed


# final effort
library(httr)
x <- GET(googleURL)
# no error but am not sure how to proceed
# the relevant HTML code to parse is 
# <div id=resultStats>About 28,200,000 results<nobr>  (0.12 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

Ay help in solving errors or parsing the httr object would be much appreciated

Comment: Woops 'there' not 'their'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a secure http connection

```
https://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow
```

`XML` is complaining about this as is `RCurl`. `httr` will download the page.

`XML` ask for an unsecured connection

```
library(XML)
googleURL <- "http://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow"
googleInfo <- htmlParse(googleURL, isURL = TRUE)
xpathSApply(googleInfo,'//*/div[@id="resultStats"]')
#[[1]]
#<div id="resultStats">About 28,200,000 results</div>
```

`RCurl` use `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE` thou it worked without for me

```
library(RCurl)
googleURL <- "https://www.google.ca/search?q=stackoverflow"
googleInfo <- getURL(googleURL,ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
googleInfo <- htmlParse(googleInfo)
# or if you want to use a cert
# system.file("CurlSSL/cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")
# googleInfo <- getURL(googleURL, cainfo = cert)
# googleInfo <- htmlParse(googleInfo)
xpathSApply(googleInfo,'//*/div[@id="resultStats"]')
#[[1]]
#<div id="resultStats">About 28,200,000 results</div>
```

`httr` use `content`

```
library(httr)
x <- GET(googleURL)
googleInfo <- htmlParse(content(x, as = 'text'))
xpathSApply(googleInfo,'//*/div[@id="resultStats"]')
#[[1]]
#<div id="resultStats">About 28,200,000 results</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. I did a google search for stackoverflow and just copied the URL - not realizing that it defaulted to https